# how to create a new file in c++ using windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, file, header-files

I want to know if there are any methods other than `file.open();` in `<windows.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you specifically state `windows.h`, the WINAPI function [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can used to create a file. At the end of the link there are multiple examples of using `CreateFile()`, but here is a simple one:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = CreateFile("test.txt",    // name of the file
                          GENERIC_WRITE, // open for writing
                          0,             // sharing mode, none in this case
                          0,             // use default security descriptor
                          CREATE_ALWAYS, // overwrite if exists
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                          0);
    if (h)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateFile() succeeded\n";
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "CreateFile() failed:" << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i used something like:-

      ofstream file("C:\\users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\abc.txt",      
ios::app);

Comment: :can u please let me know how to fetch the file's creation date so that i could use it inn my project i used stat earlier although it was not the best i guess or if u can suggest caching the stat so that

Comment: @gandhigcpp, obtaining a file's creation date is a different question. You should post another question for that. The question asked whether there was an alternative to `open()` for creating a file: `CreateFile()` is an alternative.

Comment: @hjmd:one last question
would this code change the creation date of the file if i change the system date and rerun it

Comment: @gandhigcpp No, only the last modified and access time is changed.

Comment: @hjmd:anysolutions to change the creation time as well

Comment: @hjmd:-is there any way after the creation of the file to write into it a message (current timestamp)for ex :- GetLastMessage()